# Telerik RadScheduler lowercases t in "today"! Why?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radscheduler

Telerik's Scheduler asp.net control got today misspelled. They put it with a lowercase t instead of uppercase T, how can I fix this?

Take a look here for a [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/outlook2007/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: Actually, it's not misspelt at all. It may be miscapitalised but even that is doubtful. It's neither a proper noun not a sentence. Next, you'll complain that we can run Perl scripts by executing `perl prog.pl` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<rad:RadScheduler Localization-HeaderToday="Today" />`

Answer (score 0):

I like Julien Lebosquain's answer better, but for variety here's a CSS solution.

```
.rsToday { text-transform: capitalize; }
```